# Google Map Center and InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm sorry if this has been answered somewhere else but when I add a listener to my maps it causes my markers to hide/ not load so can someone explain how to load infowindow and centre to the marker on click?

Heres my code so far:

```
<section id="wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<article>
</article>
<script>
function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '600px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';
  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    //center: coords,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.416741,-0.543854),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

  // Geolocation
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
      title:"You are here!",
  });

  // Great Fosters
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.416741,-0.543854),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png',
      title:"Great Fosters",
  });

  // St Matthews
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.432327,-0.459162),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png',
      title:"St Matthews",
  });

  // ----- STAINES HOTELS - START -----
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.435698,-0.514469),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      title:"Travel Lodge Staines",
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.432156,-0.51617),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      title:"Thames Lodge Staines",
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.43218,-0.516293),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      title:"The Boleyn Staines",
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.432534,-0.516422),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      title:"The Swan Staines",
  });
  // ----- STAINES HOTELS - END -----

}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
</script>
</section>
```

EDIT:

I have now changed my code to include the arrays and it works quite well but now I want the marker to centre on the map when clicked and I want all markers to be in the window but fitBounds doesn't seem to be doing anything. It can be shown here http://www.everythingcreative.co.uk/marker

```
<section id="wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<article>
</article>
<script>

  var markers = [
    ['Great Fosters', 51.416741,-0.543854, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png'],
    ['St Matthews', 51.432327,-0.459162, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png'],
    // Staines
    ['Travel Lodge Staines', 51.435698,-0.514469, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['Thames Lodge Staines', 51.432156,-0.51617, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['The Boleyn Staines', 51.43218,-0.516293, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['The Swan Staines', 51.432534,-0.516422, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    // Surrey
    ['The Runnymede Hotel', 51.43751,-0.537544, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['The Wheatsheaf Hotel', 51.409151,-0.592704, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['The Premier Inn Sunbury', 51.419322,-0.42248, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['The Crown Chertsey', 51.39181,-0.501861, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    // Heathrow
    ['Sofitel Heathrow', 51.473478,-0.49152, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['Marriott Heathrow', 51.481263,-0.438209, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'],
    ['Premier Inn Heathrow', 51.481615,-0.482288, 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png']
];

function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '600px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';
  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    //center: coords,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.416741,-0.543854),
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

  // Marker Control
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: markers[i][3]
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}

function AutoCenter() {
//  Create a new viewpoint bound
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
//  Go through each...
$.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
bounds.extend(marker.position);
});
//  Fit these bounds to the map
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

  // Geolocation
  var GeoMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png',
      title:"You are here!",
  });


}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
</script>
</section>
```

Comment: you are reusing the same variable `marker` for all the markers hence they are not stored anywhere and the handle is lost. you could create an array and store all the created markers in that array and then call each and use markerName.visible('true')

Comment: Hi how do I do that? Or can you guide me to where I can learn about arrays?

Comment: Actually I understand now but how do I define the icon and infowindow in an array?

Comment: it would be like 
`var markerArrays = [], marker1,marker2,marker3;
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.432534,-0.516422),
      map: map,
      icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
      title:"The Swan Staines",
  });
markersArray.push(marker1);`
so `markersArray` would have all ur markers. if you want to hide/show that marker just do `markersArray[1].visible('true')` (or false)

Comment: How will we do when we have more than 1 marker and all info windows are opened then want to center the google map? Please share your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center the map on a marker when it is clicked, change your code to do that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
        // center on marker
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        // open the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

for fitBounds to work, you have to pass the .extend method a google.maps.LatLng object. The simplest way to do that given your existing code would be to put it in your "marker control" loop:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: markers[i][3]
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```